# Select entire Handsontable column with icon click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, handsontable

I want each column in my table to have an icon that when clicked, will select the entire column. I have this working for the first (not fixed) column with a button, but cannot get the  for each icon working. Also, any idea why the last column (2018) has more width and the horizontal scroll never seems to meet the end? Thanks in advance.

**jQuery**

```
container.handsontable("loadData", getData());

$("button#selectFirst").on('click', function () {
    //container.handsontable("selectCell", 0, 4)
    container.handsontable("selectCell", 0, 4, 5, 4)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/5/

Comment: you can select the row with the index of th [http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/6/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Thanks again. You are a genius, and a huge help.

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Is it possible to put an image inside the table (not headers)? The cell types are numeric, date, checkbox, etc but can these images be appended maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/7/

Comment: This would be to select a row, rather than column - like in Excel.

Comment: something like this but the table scrolls, the selection seems out of place and the arrow don't show i have to add a letter to click the span [http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/8/)

Comment: you have to change the css to prevent displacement on the selected border and add false on the selectCell[http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/9/)

Comment: Almost exact. Remember when you click to change the fields and they turn yellow? This happens for each double click. I want the fields to turn yellow only if a value has been changed, and not an accidental double click (or click of a row select arrow). Thanks again, this is working out beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a custom renderer for the arrow like this

```
var myRendererArrow = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.cellTypes.checkbox.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    $(td).empty().append("<span class='sm-moon delBlue icon-right-arrow-17' data-icon='&#xe795;'>O</span>");
    return td;
};
```

in the afterRender callback you need to add this code

```
afterRender:function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').uniform(); 
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input.htCheckboxRendererInput').prop("checked",this.checked);
        $.uniform.update();//update UniformJS
    });
//select clicked column
$(".icon-down-arrow-17").on("click",function(){
    var col=$(this).closest("th").index();
    container.handsontable("selectCell", 0, col, 5, col);
}); 
//select row only change th for tr and the column on selectCell
$(".icon-right-arrow-17").on("click",function(){
    var row=$(this).closest("tr").index();
    container.handsontable("selectCell", row, 0, row, 13,false);//false prevent scroll
});                  
}
```

to only change the background color if a value has been changed you can use the changes object inside afterChange

```
$('#example1').handsontable('getInstance').addHook('afterChange', function(changes) {
    var ele=this;
    $.each(changes, function (index, element) {
        if(element[2]!=element[3]){    //if the original value is not equal to the actual 
               $(ele.getCell(element[0],ele.propToCol(element[1])))
                    .addClass('changeInput').data("change",true);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/10/

Comment: I noticed a small error. When checking the checkboxes, they change yellow, just like the inputs. The checkboxes should be the exception. Also, when checking a checkbox, can you have that entire row select? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, one more thing. Checked rows should remain selected, when checking a new one only that row is selecting. In that aspect, checking all for the checkboxes in the header should check all checkboxes and select all rows.

Comment: The row should only be selected if the checkbox is checked. If you uncheck the checkbox, the row is still selected.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/18/](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/18/) to select all rows you need to implement something like this and change selectCell to select multiple rows

Comment: The example above doesn't seem to implement selecting more than one row, or having the rows select/deselect according to checkbox. The only change I see is the 'check all' checkbox is missing styling.

Comment: check the update [http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/19/](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Kx3/19/) it fix some bugs with checkall and the other checkbox but for the multiple select you need to change the values on the selectCell